# Makefile for several binaries and libs from different dirs

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

There is a project layout:

```
.
├── bin    # <= executables go here
├── build  # <= object files created here
├── lib    # <= libraries go here
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── bin1  # <= if there is no "lib" prefix
│   ├── bin2  # <= it must be considered as executable
│   │   ├── a.c
│   │   ├── b.c
│   │   └── foo.h
│   ├── include # <= shared .h files, nothing to build here
│   ├── libt1   # <= if there is "lib" prefix - it must be
│   │   ├── blah.c # a library
│   │   └── blah.h
│   └── libt2
└── test
```

So i want gnu make to go through every directory in src with "lib" prefix and build a static and shared library with the same name as a directory, i.e. `libt1.so` and `libt1.a` and put them all in `lib` directory. Let's assume the libraries aren't linked with each other so the don't depend on each other either.

After building libs, it must go through every directory except `include`, and bin an executable with the same name as the directory has, and put it into `bin` dir. `build` directory is used for temporary object files.

What is the best way to do this with gnu make? I want rely on implicit rules as much as it's possible.

So now i just collect all directories into variables:

```
    LIBS_TO_BUILD=$(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/lib*)
    BINS_TO_BUILD=$(filter-out $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(LIBS_TO_BUILD),\
                  $(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/*))
```

But i can't figure out how to do all other steps, how should i iterate by all dirs? Assuming, that if i'll do it "by hands" it will look like:

```
    lib/libt1.a:
        $(CC) -o build/libt1.o $(CFLAGS) -c $(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/libt1/*.c)
        ar rcs lib/libt1.a build/libt1.o
```

Comment: Which pieces do you know? Can you write a rule to build `bin/bin2`? How about `lib/libt1.a`?

Comment: @Beta, yes i know how to build it one-by-one, see edited question.

Comment: show us your current make file.  We are more than willing to debug some existing code, but are very unwilling to do your work for you.

Comment: so you want 'make' to perform a 'glob' on the 'src/' directory, and for each item found, if the first 3 chars are 'bin' then perform a compile/link with the compile outputs moved to the 'build' directory and the executable moved to the 'bin' directory   If the first 3 chars are 'lib' then perform a compile/link for compile outputs moved to the 'build' directory and the resulting library moved to the 'lib' directory.  All the while searching the current directory and the 'include' directory for header files.  and there can be any number of sub directories under 'src'.

Comment: to find a sub string: `$(findstring find,in)`

    Searches `in` for an occurrence of `find`. If it occurs, the value is find; otherwise, the value is empty. You can use this function in a conditional to test for the presence of a specific substring in a given string.   Then use: `#ifneq  $(findstring find,in) ""`  to enter the next lines if the sub string found

Comment: stepping through a list: The `foreach` function is very different from other functions. It causes one piece of text to be used repeatedly, each time with a different substitution performed on it. `$(foreach var,list,text)`  The first two arguments, `var` and `list`, are expanded before anything else is done; note that the last argument, `text`, is not expanded at the same time. Then for each word of the expanded value of `list`, the variable named by the expanded value of `var` is set to that word, and `text` is expanded.

Comment: something like this can be used to generate the file dependencies: Here is the pattern rule to generate a file of prerequisites (i.e., a makefile) called `name.d` from a C source file called `name.c`: `%.d: %.c @set -e; rm -f $@; \ $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \ sed 's,($*)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \ rm -f $@.$$$$ `

Comment: at the end of the makefile: `# include` the contents of all the `.d` files # note: the .d files contain: # <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file # I.E. the #include'd header files # wrap with `ifneg...` so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean' # `ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean" -include $(DEP) endif`

Comment: 'glob': # Note that the argument(s) to `wildcard` below should end with a '/'. # Since wildcards also return file names, we have to filter them out # to avoid duplicate directory names. # We thus use make's `dir` and `sort `functions. `DIRS := ${sort ${dir ${wildcard ${ROOT_DIRECTORY}/*/ ${ROOT_DIRECTORY}/*/*/}}} `

Comment: suggest using 3 makefiles.  1) find all the sub directories under 'src' 2) if sub directory name begins with 'lib' then invoke the makefile to create a library. 3) if sub directory name begins with 'bin' then invoke the makefile to create a executable.